# Python: Help for an object in the interpreter

Tags: python-3.x

I want to get information about the standard dunder methods in a class through the interpreter:

in order to get to the help page below I create a class in the interpreter:

```
class Test:
    pass

a = Test()
```

Then I type:

```
help(a)


Help on Test in module __main__ object:

class Test(builtins.object)
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
(END)
```

Is there a shorter way of looking up this help page in the interpreter without instantiating or even without declaring a class in order to get information about the standard dunder methods of a class?

Comment: You can also try: `help(Test())` and `help(Test)`

Comment: Is there a way to see the help without even declaring a class?

Comment: sure: `help()` drops you into an interactive help session.

Comment: I meant that specific help

Comment: no, it's not possible to get help about a class that doesn't exist.

Comment: What do you mean *"without declaring a class"*? How would you get info about something that doesn't exist?

Comment: I wanted to have the general information about the standard dunder methods of a class

Comment: @David OK, that sort of makes sense, but I'm not sure why you need it. (Cause you could just declare a dummy class like you did and check that.) Could you edit the question to clarify?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a shorter way ...

Certainly. With a little formatting it comes out like this:

```
>>> print('\n'.join(dir(object)))
__class__
__delattr__
__dir__
__doc__
__eq__
__format__
__ge__
__getattribute__
__gt__
__hash__
__init__
__init_subclass__
__le__
__lt__
__ne__
__new__
__reduce__
__reduce_ex__
__repr__
__setattr__
__sizeof__
__str__
__subclasshook__
```

Or perhaps you prefer this:

```
from pprint import pprint as pp
pp(dir(object))
```

More pedantically:

```
import builtins
pp(dir(builtins.object))
```

The "usual" dunder methods are suppressed from the help text for conciseness.
As you saw, `def` can additionally tack on `__dict__` and `__weakref__`.
A big difference between your `Test` and its parent class is its location:

```
>>> Test.__module__
'__main__'
```